# Make whatsapp prompt security code each time

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

The WhatsApp's 2 step security allows to set a code. So, whenever we re-register with the same mobile number, It will prompt for the code and will continue if it is correct.

Alternatively, WhatsApp prompt the code randomly. I mean when opening whatsapp sometimes, It will ask for the code.

But there is no specific frequency for that. It's just random.

So, my question is **By editing any file, can I make WhatsApp prompt the code each time when I open WhatsApp.**

Because I don't want other app lockers. If I am able to achieve this, it will work as an applock for WhatsApp.

Device : Yu Yureka (AO5510) Cyanogen 12 Official non rooted.

Answer (score 0):

That code input shows to help you remember the 2 Step Verfication code and Yes it is random. So it can't replace your applocker.